# Как добавить условие в тип по определению класса в TypeScript

Tags: typescript, типы-данных, типы, typescript-типы

Как мне в типе RecursivePartial добавить условие, что если T[P] является любым классом, а не просто объектом, либо массивом таких классов, то не оборачивать в RecursivePartial, а вернуть T[P]. Причем перечислить классы "extends A" не вариант, я не могу знать какие могут быть классы в передаваемом типе. Спасибо

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
[P in keyof T]?:
  T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :
  T[P] extends object ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> :
  T[P]
}

class A {
  id: number;
  constructor(data: { id: number }) {
    this.id = data.id;
  }
};

type B = {
  id: number;
  obj: {
    value1: string;
    value2: string;
  };
  item: A;
  items: A[];
}

type C = RecursivePartial<B>
```

Я хотел бы при присваивании `const c: C = {}; c.item = { id: 1 };` видеть ошибку, что `c.item` должен быть классом A

Comment: а чем не устраивает текущее решение?

Comment: @Grundy я хотел бы при присваивании 
`const c: C = {}; c.item = { id: 1 };`
видеть ошибку, что `c.item` должен быть классом A

Comment: добавь этот пример в вопрос. отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: `TS` использует структурную типизацию, и определить что переменная принадлежит пользовательскому классу невозможно. Для `TS` это равносильные типы `new A() === {id:1}`, [пример Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0CWATAXNAdgK4C2ARgKYBOq6wA9vhAC6WHBN2UAU2eRZVAJSIa6aEwAWGCADps0ALyYsogL6p1KVEwCeAB3LQAwosS8CJCpVXRyADybl8WGPAD80AIzQ8ABlQA9AFeqNr6hgAipvD2js4wCOb8VjYe3n6BwZ5AA). Так что решить поставленную задачу нельзя.